# TailwindCSS nesting not working with postCSS config

Tags: nested, tailwind-css, postcss, postcss-import

I am trying to scope tailwind styles and I am using this postcss config from Tailwind docs:

```
module.exports = {
plugins: {
  'postcss-import': {},
  'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
 }
}
```

and here is my css

```
.app-wrapper {
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;

 }
```

with this config the nesting is working fine but not all the tailwindCSS classes working as expected.

but when I change the config to the following

```
 module.exports = {
 plugins: [
     require('postcss-import'),
     require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
     require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
 ]
};
```

the classes works fine but the nesting throw the following error

> Nested @tailwind rules were detected, but are not supported.

any idea how I can get the tailwind to work as expected with the nesting enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to add parent selector for every compiled utility, add `important: '.app-wrapper',` into your tailwind config and do not wrap `@tailwind` directives

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    important: '.app-wrapper',
    // ...
};
```

This called [selector strategy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy). This way `text-red-500` utility will be compiled as

```css
.app-wrapper .text-red-500 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

Please note: if you set darkMode as class strategy in your config

```js
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    important: '.app-wrapper',
    // ...
};
```

utility `dark:text-white` (and every other dark utility) will be compiled as

```css
.app-wrapper .dark .dark\:text-white {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

So if both `dark` and `app-wrapper` classes will be placed on the SAME element (e.g. `html` or `body`) dark mode would not work. That may explain why some classes are not working when using nesting

Comment: one problem is that base styles not being prefixed with `.app-wrapper `. Wondering if there is a way to make it work?

Comment: @Vytalyi doubt aboit it. `base` styles basically are normalizeCSS and only injects [preflights](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.3.2/src/css/preflight.css) and not handles them in Tailwind way like utilities (no purging, JIT, etc).