# TailwindCSS Nesting not including media queries

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I'm using tailwind CSS and would like to nest the entire tailwind CSS base/components/utilities code in a nested CSS class so that the code will be applied when used in children of the HTML elements inside that class

I know it's possible to use a prefix system instead, but I don't want to have to modify all html class attributes, so it's not an option for me.

**main.css**

```
.webapp {
   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;
}
```

I'm using the configuration from the official documentation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "../default/pages/*.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**cmd**

```
tailwindcss --postcss -i  ./main.scss -o ./output.css --watch
```

The problem is that, in output.css, the nesting of the node responsive css class is handled properly but not the media queries

**output.css sample**

```
.webapp button,
.webapp input,
.webapp optgroup,
.webapp select,
.webapp textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    /* 1 */
    font-size: 100%;
    /* 1 */
    font-weight: inherit;
    /* 1 */
    line-height: inherit;
    /* 1 */
    color: inherit;
    /* 1 */
    margin: 0;
    /* 2 */
    padding: 0;
    /* 3 */
  }

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .lg\:static {
    position: static;
  }

  .lg\:bottom-0 {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

The nesting of .webapp class is only working outside the @media. It's the same for .hover/ and .focus/ . I would need it to include everything to make it work.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493982/tailwindcss-nesting-not-working-with-postcss-config/74501200#74501200) is what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Add @tailwind variants into your nested class